# Indirect speech? "She will tell us that he <goes/went> to ..."

Tags: reported-speech

Situation: It's June now. She is coming to see us in August. He will go to Italy in July.

Which of these sentences below is correct, and why?

> 1. She will tell us that he goes to Italy.
> 2. She will tell us that he went to Italy.

I think the latter is definitely correct, but I'm not sure about the former.

Comment: "She will tell us ..." — does that mean that "she will tell us that" in August, when _he_ is already in Italy? If so, why does "he goes to Italy" in August if he's already there? The first sentence is not valid in the situation you described, if "she will tell us that" in August.

Answer (score 1):

> She will tell us that he goes to Italy

This means that he customarily goes to Italy - perhaps every year.

> She will tell us that he went to Italy

This means that he went to Italy before she spoke.

Answer (score 0):

She will tell us that he went to Italy.  because this event has already occurred when she imparts.